# MySQL won't insert double values

Tags: java, mysql, insert, double, zero

I have a MySQL database, and I insert rows to a table from a Java class. Everything worked fine, but today, I cannot insert double values. Instead of the values, 0 is being inserted. This is my code in Java:

```
String str = "INSERT INTO PLAYERS (p_name, p_radius, p_lat, p_lon, p_offset) "; 
str += "VALUES ('"+p.getName()+"', "+p.getRadius()+", ";
str += p.getLatitude()+", "+p.getLongitude()+", "+p.getOffset()+")";

PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(str, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
st.executeUpdate();
```

I have also printed the str String and when I execute it on the MySQL Query Browser it gets inserted correctly. The String str is the following:

```
INSERT INTO PLAYERS (p_name, p_radius, p_lat, p_lon, p_offset) 
VALUES ('John', 5, 37.976088, 23.7358438, -1011)
```

This is the table create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE  PLAYERS (player_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
p_name varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
p_lat double NOT NULL,
p_lon double NOT NULL,
p_score int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
p_highscore int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
p_game_id int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
p_status int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
p_radius int(11) NOT NULL,
p_offset bigint(20) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (player_id)
)
```

I checked the table during the insert, and I saw the values being inserted correctly. After that when I refreshed the query browser the values were 0 again... So the parameterized statement didn't make a difference.

---

**Finally, I got it. I am terribly sorry, it was my mistake! I have a method that sets these values to 0, when my application ends. Thank you for your responses!**

Comment: We need the CREATE TABLE statement for the PLAYERS table -- my guess if the column you're finding zeros is INT, not DOUBLE/etc.  Also, use StringBuffer, rather than the string concatenation you have going on.

Comment: Does the insert generate any error messages? What is your locale settings for decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got it. I am terribly sorry, it was my mistake! I have a method that sets these values to 0, when my application closes. Again, I'm really sorry. My application is quite large and so I could not see this immediately. Thank you for your responses!

Answer (score 3):

You should use a parameterized statement. Try using this code instead:

```
String str = "INSERT INTO PLAYERS (p_name, p_radius, p_lat, p_lon, p_offset) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)";
PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(str, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
st.setString(1, p.getName());
st.setDouble(2, p.getRadius());
st.setDouble(3, p.getLatitude());
st.setDouble(4, p.getLongitude());
st.setInt(5, p.getOffset());
st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. But I still don't understand why it worked with my String until yesterday and today not.

Comment: @Johny I do not know what may have changed, but there is a number of factors that may have an effect on the success or failure of the operation. For example, if the string contains single quote characters or doubles are formatted European style (i.e. with ',' as the decimal separator) your results will be incorrect. That is why you should use parameterized statements: among other things, it prevents [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Ok, so from now on I will use the parameterized statement. I edited my question. I actually see the values being inserted correctly but then when I hit refresh the values are zero again...It's insane!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and the section on Supplying Values for PreparedStatement Parameters. Sometimes if you don't use parameterization it will truncate the doubles precision. Amongst other reasons it's really a good best practice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String str = "INSERT INTO PLAYERS (p_name, p_radius, p_lat, p_lon, p_offset) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; 

PreparedStatement st = connection.prepareStatement(str, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
st.setString(1, p.getName());
st.setDouble(2, p.getRadius());
st.setDouble(3, p.getLatitude());
st.setDouble(4, p.getLongitude());
st.setInt(5, p.getOffset());
st.executeUpdate();
```